# Play multiple sound devices

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, speakers, sound-card

I am trying to play songs in a game whenever I press the mic (push to talk).

#### My current problem:

If I play any songs on the loud speakers and hear on mic, there is lot of disturbance from my surroundings, which is ruining the experience for others.

#### My attempts:

For this after researching, I found that I can have virtual input (mic?) and virtual output (speakers?) sound devices which catches the system sound and plays through the microphone, without the disturbance of outside noise. For this, I used `Voicemeeter` software. This is letting me play songs from youtube or anywhere else when I press the mic.

#### The problem:

The problem here is I can't hear any system sound when I set `voice output` as `Voicemeeter`. So, though others are able to hear songs I am unable to hear it.

For this, again, after doing some research, I found that I should enable "stereo mix" in recording tab of sound settings. But I am unable to see it though I even set to "show disabled devices". To fix this, I found a driver software from stereomixplus.com - When I installed this, it is asking me to purchase license. So I just avoided this.

#### What I want?

I want to be able to play multiple audio devices (High definition audio and virtual audio to play songs) together. So that others and even I can hear playing songs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Voicemeeter and connect it to your main speaker, you may set Voicemeeter Virtual Input as default playback device, because Voicemeeter can take exclusive access to your output device... preventing any other applications to use it. See user manual step ZERO: https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf